# Sending Ember Highcharts events back to parent component

Tags: ember.js, highcharts, event-handling

I'm using Ember 2.3 and have built a controller around Ember Highcharts. When a chart point is clicked I send that event back to the controller via the following nasty bit of code added to the highcharts configuration object:

```
Graph.__container__.lookup('controller:accounts.account.outlets.outlet.ratings').send('pointClick', event);
```

(I know this is fundamentally wrong and should be using getOwner.lookup for the container reference)

This works without issue, but I'm now refactoring this controller to a component and can't think how to pass the graph event back to the component as components are not registered in the app container.

Any pointers to how to achieve this would be very much appreciated!

Thanks.

UPDATE

I've just discovered that I can send an action to a component from the Highcharts event function:

```
Graph.__container__.lookup('component:ratingsGraph').send('pointClick', event)
```

But this seems to create a new instance of the component, rather than send to the existing instance. I guess that makes sense as components aren't singletons.

Very frustrating!

Comment: Could you recreate your current setup on https://ember-twiddle.com/ or http://emberjs.jsbin.com/?

Comment: Not without a lot of work, sorry. I've just discovered that I can get access to a component via the container, but as there can be multiple instances of each component, how would I get the right one?

Comment: Does this help? https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.3.0/components/triggering-changes-with-actions/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately not. The issue is not with bubbling actions within a hierarchy of ember components. The issue is down to the fact that you add bespoke functionality to Highcharts events (e.g. a click on the graph), by passing a literal function definition to Highcharts via its configuration parameters. I'm not able to pass a calling object reference to this function, so cannot get access back to the calling Ember component. I solved this when it was wrapped in a controller by accessing the controller from the Ember container. I can't do this for a component.

Comment: I think I may have to go down to route of accessing an Ember service from the container, then trigger an Ember event and listen for it in the component - a horrible workaround!

Comment: @InTooDeep So you need to pass a function and use its return value? Closure actions seem perfect to me. https://alisdair.mcdiarmid.org/ember-closure-actions-have-return-values/

Comment: Nope, can't do this as the 'action' is coming from HighCharts and not the component. Solved it now, see solution, but thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Some days you can't see the wood for the trees!

Instead of defining the highcharts event function in the highcharts configuration parameters, I simply defined it within the component and passed it to highcharts. This enabled me to use a closure to hold reference to the defining component.

Doh!

Comment: I think i'm trying to do something similar. Did you have problems with the Highchart click event being lost? Do you have a simple example? thanks! I posted a question here. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36211027/highchart-series-event-lost-in-ember)

Comment: If you're trying to get the component from the container (via the highcharts click event) then the event is not lost, you're not getting reference to the correct component (components are not singletons like controllers etc). You need to define your click event within your component (with reference to the component), then add to the hichcharts options.